# Running eBay TurboLister 2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine

I was wondering if there was any way I could run eBay TurboLister 2 tool on Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Wine 1.6.2.  I got it to install but not run.  If anybody has anything to contribute to this, I'd gladly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: You should at least have posted what error you got and what steps you already took to solve it.

Comment: When I would try to run it, it just wouldn't open.  No error message or anything would show. I wasn't sure what to do next. The first time I tried to run it would load about a third of the way, then hang.  Each time I opened it after that it wouldn't show any indication that I opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing how all recent releases of TurboLister 2 are [listed with a 'garbage' rating on WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2466) it's highly unlikely that you will be able to get it to work on your machine.